# ContourLogLinearPlot

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale

Title says it all: how can I do a `ContourPlot` with a logarithmic $x$-axis?

I am attempting to replicate the graph of [ISO 226:2003](https://www.iso.org/standard/34222.html) (see first image) but

```
ContourPlot[
  spl2ll[spl, freq],
  {freq, 0, 13000},
  {spl, 0, 130},
  Contours -> Range[0,100,10]
]
```

generates something like the second image.

[image: ISO 226 equal-loudness contours]
[image]

Comment: Use the option `ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", None}`

Comment: Thank you! That works perfectly.